# Find all integral solutions for the Diophantine Equations $x^4 - x^2y^2 + y^4 = z^2$ and $x^4 + x^2y^2 + y^4 = z^2$.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

> Find all integral solutions for the Diophantine Equations $$x^4 - x^2y^2 + y^4 = z^2$$ and $$x^4 + x^2y^2 + y^4 = z^2$$

I basically think that to solve these equations we need to use the fact that all Pythagoras Triplets are like $(k \cdot 2mn, k \cdot (m^2 - n^2), k \cdot (m^2 + n^2))$. The above equations can be modified a little bit to make all the terms perfect squares. Then the first equation would be $$(x^2 - y^2)^2  + (xy)^2 = z^2$$ and the second one would be $$z^2 + (xy)^2 = (x^2 + y^2)^2$$

I have found no other clues. Please help me proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: If you subtract them, you get $x^2y^2=0$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr They are different questions. It's not like that they both have the same solutions.

Comment: So, you're asking two questions, not a simultaneous system.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes.

Answer (score 8):

[*Edited* to add the citations of Euler and others from Dickson]

Each of $E_\pm: x^4 \pm x^2 y^2 + y^4 = z^2$ is an elliptic curve.
It turns out that in each case a Fermat-style "descent"
suffices to find all solutions; in practice these days
such questions are solved by reducing the curve to standard form
and then either using software such as J.Cremona's **mwrank**,
or consulting tables of elliptic curve
if the curve is simple enough to be in the tables $-$ as is
the case here where Tingley's "Antwerp" tables already contain
both curves.  The solutions are $(x,y,z) = (t,0,\pm t^2)$ and,
for $E_-$, also $(x,y,z) = (t,\pm t, \pm t^2)$.

One easy way to map $x^4 \pm x^2 y^2 + y^4 = z^2$ to an
elliptic curve in "Weierstrass form"
is to let $t = x/y$ (assuming $y \neq 0$, but if $y=0$ then it's easy),
so that $t^4 \pm t^2 + 1$ is a square, and then let $X = t^2$ so
$X^3 \pm X^2 + X = Y^2$.  The curve is then in the extended Weierstrass
form
$$
Y^2 + a_1 X Y + a_3 Y = X^3 + a_2 X^2 + a_4 X + a_6
$$
with $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_6) = (0,\pm1,0,1,0)$.
[These curves $Y^2 = X^3 \pm X^2 + X$ are not *isomorphic* with $E_\pm$,
but they are "2-isogenous", which is good enough for our purposes,
and in any case the "descent" approach requires solving $Y^2 = X^3 \pm X^2 + X$
as well.]
We can now look up these coefficients in the tables, or enter them into
**mwrank** and **gp**, to find that for both choices of $\pm$ sign
there are finitely many rational solutions,
with $X=0$ and (for $E_-$) also $X=1$.  Thus the only solutions
with $xy=0$ are those with $x=\pm y$ for $E_-$, etc.

[*Added later*: since this is a natural question that is tractable
but nontrivial, it is not surprising that it's been asked and answered before.
Indeed Dickson's *History of the Theory of Numbers, Vol. II* devotes
several pages to such equations (Chapter XXII, starting on page 634),
starting with Euler's work on $x^4+kx^2y^2+y^4=\Box$.  The present
question concerns the cases $k=\pm 1$, called $E_\pm$ above.
The result on $E_-$ was already stated in Euler's *Algebra* (1770),
but without proof, which was first supplied in the early 1800's.
As for $E_+$, "R. Adrain$^{112}$ proved by descent that
$x^4+x^2y^2+y^4 \neq \Box$", presumably excluding the trivial $xy=0$;
footnote 112 refers to *The Math. Diary*, New York, 1, 1825, 147-150,
with citations of later work by Genocchi (1855; he'd later use elliptic-curve
descent to prove Fermat for exponent 7) and Pocklington (1914, but still
more than a century ago).]

Comment: Heavy weaponry, only to few people. Best regards.

Comment: In this case the modern "heavy weaponry" really comes down to
a systematization of what Fermat already showed how to do.
I wouldn't be surprised if these specific results are already
cited in Dickson's *History of the Theory of Numbers, Vol. II*,
perhaps due to Euler himself.

Comment: I hope you don't see this as too chatty, but I did not know that a person as famous as Professor Noam D. Elkies used this site.

Comment: Famous or not, I contribute more to Mathoverflow than Stackexchange, but yes, I sometimes find on this site (especially among the "featured questions") a question that touches on my expertise or strikes my fancy for some other reason.

Comment: It is certainly very good thing that Professor Elkies is contributing StackExchange.  I would say however that  "modern" notion of descent (extremely important to elliptic curves!) is essentially the same as Fermat but with a very sophisticated elaboration (evolution indeed!).

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- I feel but I have no proof that there are only the trivial solutions $(x,y,z)= (t,0,t^2),(0,t,t^2)$. I give here an outline of what could perhaps lead to a proof.
$$x^4-x^2y^2+y^4=z^2\iff (x^2-y^2)^2+x^2y^2=z^2\qquad (1)$$ Hence, as it is well known, 
$$\begin{cases}x^2-y^2=t^2-s^2\\xy=2ts\\z=t^2+s^2\end{cases}\qquad (2)$$
It follows in particular $$x^2+s^2=t^2+y^2\qquad (3)$$ The general solution of $(3)$, which likely as for Pithagorean triples comes from an identity easily verified, is given by
$$\begin{cases}2x=aX+bY\\2s=aY-bX\\2t=aX-bY\\2y=aY+bX\end{cases}\qquad (4)$$
where $a,b$ are arbitrary integers and $X,Y$ two parameters.

In any case, because of $(3)$,  $x$ and $y$ must have the form, given by $(4)$, for certain integer values $a,b,X,Y$. However, in order to use parameters $t$ and $s$ we need besides to fit our values with the constraint $xy=2ts$ so we get the condition
$$(aX+bY)(aY+bX)=2(aX-bY)(aY-bX)\iff 3ab(X^2+Y^2)=(a^2+b^2)XY$$
It follows $$\left(\frac XY\right)^2-\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{3ab}\right)\left(\frac XY\right)+1=0$$
Hence $$ \frac{6abX}{Y}= a^2+b^2\pm \sqrt{ (a^2+b^2)^2-(6ab)^2}$$ so the equation $$(a^2+b^2)^2-(6ab)^2=c^2\iff (a^2+b^2+6ab)(a^2+b^2-6ab)=c^2$$

It could be useful perhaps for someone. I stop here the comment.

Comment: And $(t,t,t^2)$?

Comment: Equally trivial. Believe it or not I always write  $xyz=0$ when I want to refer only to the two above solutions. It was a distraction so I did not put the solution that you say.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated*

We can try to find solutions ourself.

---

**Equation 1.**
$\quad x^4+x^2y^2+y^4 = z^2.$

Let 
$$\gcd(x,y) = m,\quad x=mX,\quad y=mY,\quad z=m^2Z,$$
then 
$$X^4+X^2Y^2+Y^2=Z^2,\quad\gcd(X,Y)=1.$$

$$(X^2+XY+Y^2)(X^2-XY+Y^2)=Z^2,\quad\gcd(X,Y)=1.$$
Multipliers in the left part are the same parity. If they are even, then both $X$ and $Y$ are even and coprime, but this conditions are incompatible. So the multipliers are odd, and if they can have only odd common divider, which are the divider of expressions 
$$3(X^2+XY+Y^2)-(X^2-XY+Y^2) = 2(X+Y)^2$$
and
$$3(X^2-XY+Y^2)-(X^2+XY+Y^2) = 2(X-Y)^2,$$
so numbers $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ share a common odd divider. And this odd divider must divide both their sum $2X$ and difference $2Y$, when $X$ and $Y$ are coprime. This contradiction proves that
$$\gcd(X^2-XY+Y^2,X^2+XY+Y^2)=1.$$

Product of coprime positive factors is the square of an integer. Consequently, each of them is the square of coprime integers:
$$\begin{cases}
X^2+XY+Y^2=U^2,\\
X^2-XY+Y^2=V^2,\\
\gcd(X,Y)=1,\\
\gcd(U,V)=1.
\end{cases}$$
So
$$\begin{cases}
X^2+Y^2=\dfrac{U^2+V^2}2,\\
2XY= U^2-V^2.
\end{cases}$$
Right part of the second equality is even, so $U$ and $V$ has the same parity and are odd. Then, $XY$ is even, when $X$ and $Y$ are coprime. 
The task is symmetric in the variables $X$ and $Y$, let $X$ is odd and $Y$ is even:
$$X\cdot\frac Y2 = \dfrac{U+V}2\frac{U-V}2.$$
Note than $\dfrac{U+V}2$ and $\dfrac{U-V}2$ are coprime, because any their common divider also divides their sum $U$ and difference $V$.

The last equation has а solution
$$X=ac,\quad\dfrac Y2=bd,\quad \dfrac{U+V}2=ad,\quad\dfrac{U-V}2=bc,$$
so
$$X=ac,\quad Y=2bd,\quad U=ad+bc,\quad V=ad-bc,\quad Z=\pm(a^2d^2-b^2c^2),$$
where 
$$\gcd(ac,2bd)=\gcd(ad,bc)=1.$$
Thus, $a$ and $c$ are odd and $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are pairwise coprime numbers.
That numbers must satisfy to equation
$$(ac)^2+4(bd)^2=(ad)^2+(bc)^2,$$
or
$$a^2(c^2-d^2)=b^2(c^2-4d^2).$$
$$\dots$$

**Equation 2.**

If 
$$3(xy)^2+z^2=(x^2+y^2)^2,$$
then
$$
\begin{cases}
xy=2m-1,\\
z=\dfrac{3x^2y^2-1}2,\\
x^2+y^2=\dfrac{3x^2y^2+1}2.
\end{cases}
$$
So
$$(xy+1)(3xy+1)=2(x+y)^2.$$
Then you can use the fact that equation
$$mn=p^2$$
has solutions
$$m=a^2c,\quad n=b^2c,\quad p=abc,$$
for $$m\in\left\{\dfrac{xy+1}2,xy+1\right\}$$